# What is a "statement batch"?

Tags: sql-server, terminology

I know what a statement is and I know what a batch is, but what is a "statement batch"? T-SQL's documentation uses the term in [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) [places](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oacreate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) that I've found.

> If a TRY...CATCH construct is not available, the statement batch is terminated.

> Any error that occurs in a THROW statement causes the statement batch to be terminated.

> The created OLE object is automatically destroyed at the end of the Transact-SQL statement batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A batch of SQL statements is a group of two or more SQL statements or a single SQL statement that has the same effect as a group of two or more SQL statements. In some implementations, the entire batch statement is executed before any results are available

- statement batch
- batch of statements

All the same

Just think about the fact that you can have a single statement or multiple statements and therefore a batch.